# Whether this expression will always be calculated from left to right?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I learn JavaScript (ECMAScript 6) through the books. Is it safe definition?

```
let n = 8, k = n/2;
```

Whether this expression will always be calculated from *left to right*? Or maybe *it depends on the interpreter* and I am to write such:

```
let n = 8;
let k = n/2;
```

?

Comment: JS is in general always evaluated strictly left-to-right (sans more or less obvious associativity rules), it must not be reordered by the interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Binding List](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-BindingList) is always evaluated from left to right. So it's **safe to use**.

If you're interested in the details, you can also have a look at the [Specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-let-and-const-declarations-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

Comment: That's not the comma operator, to be precise, it's a [BindingList](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#prod-BindingList).

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware that there is a specific construct for this case :)